# libreactnativejni.so is built as elf32-i386 on 64bit android ndk (linux)

Tags: android-ndk, react-native

EDIT: I managed to built x86_64 version of `libreactnativejni.so` (see my answer). However it didn't resolved my problem.

To sum up what I learned here is:

### You cannot test android components, which are using native libraries on Linux, because "libandroid.so" (core android lib), doesn't exists for Linux.

### Original question:

My goal is to run tests on my Linux box using PowerMockito similar to [RootViewTest.java](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/RootViewTest.java#L67).
Not sure how react-native team managed to run this test, but from my experience mocking `Arguments.createArray` is not possible, without loading jni library `reactnativejni`. Reason is that `Arguments.createArray()` calls `WritableNativeArray` which in static initializer [ReactBridge.staticInit()](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/WritableNativeArray.java#L22) calls `SoLoader.loadLibrary("reactnativejni")`.

So I thought I've no other option, but [compile this reactnativejni shared library](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/building-from-source.html) for linux, using 64bit [android-ndk-r10e](http://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.zip)

I managed to load this jni lib and test my code using:

```
ndkDir=$(pwd)/react-ndk/all/x86 \
  JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=\".:$ndkDir\"" \
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$ndkDir:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" ./gradlew app:test
```

But test failed with:

```
libreactnativejni.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 (Possible cause: architecture word width mismatch)
```

Checked platform with objdump:

```
objdump -s --section .comment libreactnativejni.so

libreactnativejni.so:     file format elf32-i386
```

My question how is possible that 64 bit ndk produced 32 bit library and how to force to produce 64 bit.

Library build script is written as gradle script:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/ReactAndroid/build.gradle#L199

Comment: It is worthwhile to read [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2814), maybe you will choose to stay 32 bit while FB struggles with this issue.

Comment: Not sure staying on 32bit is option. If I understood correctly 64bit Android arm can load 32bit libs. However, I would like to run test on my 64bit PC machine. Can I load 32bit jni lib on X86_64?

Comment: Wait a sec… if you expect your so to run on Linux, you need a different starting point. Android binaries don't work on Linux, Linux binaries don't work on Android. The kernels are almost the same, but C runtimes are significantly different. You can test your code on emulator, or on Chromebook.

Comment: I've replaced all occurences of -std=c++1y with -std=c++11 in all Android.mk files and finally X86_64 reactnativejni.so built succesfully. Now I'm going to test my theory from comment above. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not going to run Android libs on Linux or vice versa. My goal is to run tests on my Linux box - get to the point I can use PowerMockito like in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/RootViewTest.java#L67. The reason why I'm doing all this is I would like to mock Arguments.createArray(). But that's not straight forward as calls ReactBridge.staticInit which calls SoLoader.loadLibrary("reactnativejni"); I believe reactnativejni is not  important for mocking, but I cannot skip ReactBridge.staticInit as it's sDidInit is private.

Comment: Ok, now I probably understand what you mean. After lot of struggle I finally compiled that jni lib for X86_64, but loading is failing with: `/libreactnativejni.so: libandroid.so: cannot open shared object`. I guess there is no libandroid.so for Linux. So I was condemned to failure from very beginning. Last question here is how react-native managed to run test https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/test/java/com/facebook/react/RootViewTest.java#L67 then.

Comment: I have a dream that once this will be possible. I believe that porting the Android runtime to Linux, Mac, and even Windows for the sole purpose of running Java unit tests on the build machine, is a project that can be achieved in few man months. Creating such mock of `libreactnativejni.so` is probably harder, and definitely less scalable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question (thank Alex for good APP_ABI lead). To compile x86_64 variant of `reactnativejni` follow this steps:

1. Update APP_ABI to `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86_64 x86` in file `ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/Application.ml`

The next problem is dependency [jsc-android](https://github.com/facebook/android-jsc), which is not build for X86_64 target. There is alternative [jsc-android-buildscripts](https://github.com/SoftwareMansion/jsc-android-buildscripts) which is also built for X86_64.

2. Extract folder X86_64 directly from aar and put it in `ReactAndroid/build/third-party-ndk/jsc/jni/x86_64`

However compilation will be failing on X86_64 with errors: `lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++1y or -std=gnu++1y`

3. Fix that error, by replacing all occurrences of `-std=c++1y` with `-std=c++11` in all `Android.mk` files.
4. Now you can start build with: `./gradlew buildReactNdkLib`
5. Optionally you might need to clean build folder with `./gradlew cleanReactNdkLib`

Built `reactnativejni` - `libreactnativejni.so` will be present in `ReactAndroid/build/react-ndk/all/x86_64`.

But unfortunately `libreactnativejni.so` will not work on Linux, as it has dependency on `libandroid.so`, which doesn't exists for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

ReactAndroid explicitly [requests](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/Application.mk#L3) 32-bit targets. If you wish, you can replace this line to read

```
APP_ABI := all
```

Comment: Very helpful. However there is one more showstopper. android-jsc seems not be compiled for X86_64. Unpacked aar https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webkit/android-jsc/r174650 only has shared libs for x86 armeabi and armeabi-v7a. Not sure how I'm going to resolve this.

Comment: Ok luckely thereis https://github.com/SoftwareMansion/jsc-android-buildscripts which builds also X86_64. Now only resolve build errors.